# Make floating div clear if space is missing

Tags: css, html, css-float

I would like to make the "color-boxes" clear the text on the right but always make a first full line without any jumps. I don't know the actual length of the text so it has to be dynamic.

All the color-boxes are fixed width and height with float left on them.
The text area is float right with width set.

[image]

Comment: With JS you can use the modulus operator `%` and assign the css based on if the text height doesn't match the color boxes break point. This way they'll line up irrelevant of text size.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it. I know that my "color-block" build 111px in height so i symply set the height using some basic math. Ty John Sooter for getting me on the right track.

$('.w3').height(Math.ceil($('.w3').height() / 111.0) * 111);

w3 is the class on my text block.